# React loader spinner doesn't render

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a web signup page with reactjs, nodejs, Yup, styled-components and Formik.
My goal is to add a loader from react-loader-spinner when i click `Login button` after successful submit. But this code didn't help, it didn't make the loader (ThreeDots) appear at all.

Please help, i'm new in react, Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
import * as Loader from 'react-loader-spinner';
```

.

```
<Formik
          initialValues={{
            email: '',
            password: ''
          }}
          validationSchema={Yup.object({
            email: Yup.string().email('Invalid email').required('Required'),
            password: Yup.string()
              .min(8, 'Password is too short')
              .max(30, 'Password is too long')
              .required('Required')
          })}
          onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
            console.log(values);
          }}
        >
          {({ isSubmitting }) => (
            <Form>
              <TextInput
                name="email"
                type="text"
                label="Email :"
                placeholder="mail@mail.com"
                icon={<FiMail />}
              />

              <TextInput
                name="password"
                type="password"
                label="Password :"
                placeholder="*************"
                icon={<FiLock />}
              />

              <ButtonGroup>
                {!isSubmitting && (
                  <StyledFormButton type="submit">Login</StyledFormButton>
                )}
                {isSubmitting && (
                  <Loader
                    type="ThreeDots"
                    color={colors.theme}
                    height={49}
                    width={100}
                    ariaLabel="loading"
                  />
                )}
              </ButtonGroup>
            </Form>
          )}
        </Formik>
```

I already imported this in App.js:

```
import "react-loader-spinner/dist/loader/css/react-spinner-loader.css";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loader-spinner), you should change your import like this

```
import { ThreeDots } from  'react-loader-spinner'  // or another spinner
```

And instead of the `<Loader ..../>` in your code, use it like this

```
return (
  ...
  <ThreeDots
    height="100"
    width="100"
    color='grey'
    ariaLabel='loading'
  />
  ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks but i need to use ThreeDots loader only, 
i already read the doc.

Comment: @michael I've updated the answer with the ThreeDots loader

Comment: Hmmm, i thought i should use `<Loader    type="ThreeDots"    />` . Thanks.